# how to compare a user entered password to an encrypted password in a database using BCrypt

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, bcrypt

I have a task where I need to verify a users password using BCrypt before they can retrieve their transaction details out of a database, the password for the account has already been hashed and put into the database. I am new to BCrypt and I have no idea where to begin. I just need some help understanding how BCrypt works and also I need to know how to compare a user entered password (via an Input Box) to an encrypted password in a database so that the user can retrieve their information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to verify a password using BCrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22525091/how-to-verify-a-password-using-bcrypt)

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to BCrypt and I have no idea where to begin

This can be a good start. read the details [here](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/)

> I just need some help understanding how BCrypt works

A .Net port of jBCrypt implemented in C#. It uses a variant of the Blowfish encryption algorithm’s keying schedule, and introduces a work factor, which allows you to determine how expensive the hash function will be, allowing the algorithm to be "future-proof".

> I need to know how to compare a user entered password (via an Input Box) to an encrypted password in a database so that the user can retrieve their information.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/475262/UseplusBCryptplustoplusHashplusYourplusPasswords) article contains a full example of how to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much, all this information is very helpful.

Comment: I have a question though, when comparing a user entered password to an encrypted password in a database, do you need to retrieve and decrypt the password and then compare it or do you just compare the user entered password with the hashed password in the code? Because the password I am trying to verify has already been encrypted and entered into the database but I do not have the code for it. Do you get what I mean?