# How to verify a password using BCrypt

Tags: c#, bcrypt, password-hash

How do I check if a user entered password matches a password that has been hashed and stored into a database by somebody else. Normally you would use this right?:

```
bool value = BCryptHelper.CheckPassword("Tom123", passwordHash);
```

So what if you don't have the passwordHash variable which contains the hashed password?

I don't have a great understanding of how BCrypt works so I think I am missing something very simple.

Comment: encrypt the password user has entered, and compare the hash

Comment: `passwordHash` is what you get from the database. It is the hash of the password the user entered when they created the account.

Comment: @Ehsan That is really no help and doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I know what the passwordHash is. This doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: @Maattt encrypting the password that user has entered will give you the hashed password. If the user has entered the correct password then the hash should be the same as the one that is stored in the database.

Comment: `"what if you don't have the passwordHash variable which contains the hashed password?`"

Comment: `How do I check if a user entered password matches a password that has been hashed and stored into a database` and `what if you don't have the passwordHash variable which contains the hashed password` are mutually exclusive statements. How do you check a hash that is stored in the database without having the hash that is stored in the database?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What I mean is-is that the password was hashed and stored in the database by another person. The user entered password isn't a password that is being created, the user entered password is the password the user is inputting so that they can access their account information in the database. When I say I don't have the passwordHash variable I mean that the password was hashed by another person so I don't have the variable that contains the hashed password so I can't use that variable in the BCrypt.CheckPassword.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I still don't see how that is answering my question. All you said was what the passwordHash is but I already know what it is. Perhaps you don't understand the question.

Comment: @Ehsan I know that, that still doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint to the answer. You can follow the link for further detailed information.

```
string salt = BCryptHelper.GenerateSalt(6);
var passwordHash= BCryptHelper.HashPassword("Tom123", salt);

bool value = BCryptHelper.CheckPassword("Tom123", passwordHash);
```

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1267/entry-3301-c%23-using-bcrypt-in-a-net-application-why-its-better-than-sha-or-md5/

Comment: I know how this code works, my problem is that I am not the one who has hashed and stored the password. It was done by somebody else so therefore I do not have the passwordHash variable to use in that line of code to check the password against the password the user is entering.

Comment: Then you should get the password hash to decrypt it otherwise you will be a hacker!!!

Comment: yeah sorry guys I was over thinking it way too much.